# Perl: Using data from an anonymous hash

Tags: bash, perl, whois

I am adding on to another developers code, we are both new to perl I am trying to take a list of IPs and run it through whois. I am unsure how to access the data in the anonymous hash, how do I use it?
He told me the data was stored inside one. This is the only instance I could find mentioning a hash:

```
## Instantiate a reference to an anonymous hash (key value pair)
my $addr = {};
```

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an anonymous hash:

```
my $anon_hash = {
  key1 => 'Value 1',
  key2 => 'Value 2',
  key3 => 'Value 3',
}
```

If you want to access an individual value:

```
my $value = $anon_hash->{key1};
say $anon_hash->{key2};
```

If you want to update an individual value:

```
$anon_hash->{key3} = 'New value 3';
```

If you want to add a new key/value pair:

```
$anon_hash->{key4} = 'Value 4';
```

You can also use all of the standard hash functions (e.g. [`keys()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys)). You just need to "deference" your hash reference - which means putting a '%' in front of it.

So, for example, to print all the key/value pairs:

```
foreach my $key (keys %$anon_hash) {
  say "$key : $anon_hash->{$_}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous hash is the `{}` part. It returns a reference which can be stored in a scalar variable, like in your example:

```
my $addr = {};
```

To see the structure, you can print it with [`Data::Dumper`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data::Dumper):

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $addr;
```

It might show you something like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'c' => 1,
          'a' => 2
        };
```

You access the hash keys using the arrow operator:

```
print $addr->{"a"}
```

Like how you would access a regular hash, but with the arrow operator in between.

You can dereference the reference by putting a hash sigil in front

```
%$addr

# compare %addr  %$addr
#          hash   hashref dereferenced
```